Is it possible to connect two different JFrames to one single class?
I make two forms but I have this problem where my second form that will appear after we press a button on the first form could not get the data from the subclass. The plan was I want to only use one single class.
So first form is an input, we input data and it'll be put into the subclass A. Then the second form will go get the input from the subclass A. The best I could do is to use getText() but I want to make my program object oriented without a database or using SQL. The IDE I use is Apache NetBeans.
private void bCetakActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    output.lbNim.setText(kls.getNim());
    output.lbKode.setText(tKode.getText());
    output.lbJudul.setText(tJudul.getText());
    output.lbPinjam.setText(tTgl.getText());
    
    this.setVisible(false);
    output.show();
}

The kls is subclass and getNim() is a function in kls. I want it to be like that, not getText().

Your application should have one and only one JFrame.  You create multiple JPanels for your JFrame.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, Creating a GUI With Swing.  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Study the tutorial.

@leblanc I don't know from where you deduce that there can only be one frame, it is totally false, there can not only be internal frames, but external ones, which can be shown or hidden at will.

@MarcePuente it's good practice to only use one JFrame, then use children/dialogues. It is how swing is designed to work. You can have multiple JFrames, but in general you shouldn't.

I think you could use the Model, View, Controller (MVC) pattern. Lets say you have a model, that models your data.
class MyModel{
    int a1, a2, a3, b1, b2;
    String s1, s2, s3, z1, z2;
}


This is such a simple example that the controller is not necessary, but we'll keep it for illustration purposes.
class Controller{
    public Controller(MyModel m){
        model = m;
    }
    private MyModel model;
    public void setA1(int v){
        model.a1 = v;
    }
    public int getA1(){
        return model.a1;
    }
    
    public String getZ1(){
        return model.z1 == null ? "" : model.z1;
    }
    public void setZ1(String s){
        model.z1 = s;
    }
}

Finally you have a view that lets you operate the controller and show your data.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
public class View{  
    private final Controller controller;
    JFrame frame;
    public View(Controller c){
        controller = c;
    }

    public void startADialog(ActionEvent evt){
        JDialog log = new JDialog(frame, "Set A Values", true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("a1");
        JTextField box = new JTextField(5);
        box.setText("" + controller.getA1() );
        JButton finish = new JButton("finish");
        finish.addActionListener( e ->{
            controller.setA1( Integer.parseInt( box.getText() ) );
            log.setVisible(false);
        });
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(label);
        p.add(box);
        p.add(finish);
        log.setContentPane(p);
        log.pack();
        log.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void startBDialog(ActionEvent evt){
        JDialog log = new JDialog(frame, "Set B Values", true);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("z1");
        JTextField box = new JTextField(5);
        box.setText(controller.getZ1());
        JButton finish = new JButton("finish");
        finish.addActionListener( e ->{
            controller.setZ1( box.getText() );
            log.setVisible(false);
        });
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(label);
        p.add(box);
        p.add(finish);
        log.setContentPane(p);
        log.pack();
        log.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void buildAndShowGui(){
        frame = new JFrame("Sample View");
        JButton a = new JButton("Set A Things");
        JButton b = new JButton("Set B Things");
        frame.add(a, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        a.addActionListener(this::startADialog);
        b.addActionListener(this::startBDialog);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Controller c = new Controller(new MyModel());
        View v = new View(c);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( v::buildAndShowGui);
    }

}


Click on the "A" button and you get to modify A parameters. Click on the "B" button and you modify B parameters.

The pattern is model-view-controller, not controller-view-model.  The model is one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.  The view is the GUI.  The controllers (plural) are the Swing Actions and Listeners.

@GilbertLeBlanc I don't get your first sentence. I did write it as MVC. I often separate use a single controller for different views. The model could have getters/setters and the controller would safely call those from the ActionListeners or other Actionable methods.

I could improve it, but maybe you're writing an answer, or feel it should be closed. Or if you want to improve it that is fine too.

This example illustrates the design principle @GilbertLeBlanc mentions.

@trashgod I think my example illustrates it too. You example isn't very explicit. Like I said I can improve this one, but I suspect nobody cares so I won't bother.

@matt: My intent was only to amplify on the original comment; of course, I defer to you entirely on any change to your example, which I note appears to be correctly synchronized.

@trashgod I see, I didn't quite get the point of Gilbert Le Blanc's comment. If I look at your comment towards OP then it makes sense. Your example is definitely something OP could emulate.
